# Form select query output - array

Tags: php, html, forms, url, select

I want my select form to return query like this

```
http://myexamplesite.com/store/?brand=nike+adidas+woodland
```

but it returns

```
http://myexamplesite.com/store/?brand=nike&brand=adidas&brand=woodland
```

What kind of change I have to make for the form

I tried setting the select - `name="brand[]"` name=`"brand[0]"`
but it returns

```
brand%5B0%5D=adidas&brand%5B0%5D=nike
```

the form select element is inside a for each loop

Comment: Just implode the values in PHP instead: `$brands = is_array($_GET['brand']) ? implode('+', $_GET['brand']) : $_GET['brand'];`

Comment: What is the name of your ``<select>`` field? Do you have one field or multiples?

Comment: @Nick, Thank you I am using WordPress so we have a method get_query_var() instead of $_GET https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_query_var/

Comment: @kmoser its multifield selection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do:

- create a hidden form input named `brand`
- rename your select to something else eg. `brand-select`
- intercept the form submit with `onsubmit`, construct the correct string and give it as a value to the `brand` input
- disable the `brand-select` input so it is not sent to the server
- finally submit the form

I made a quick example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/ndrewka/pen/Yzzembb):

HTML:

```
<form method="get" id="form" action="https://postman-echo.com/get">
<select name="brand-select" id="brand-select" multiple>
  <option value="nike">Nike</option>
  <option value="adidas">Adidas</option>
  <option value="woodland">woodland</option>
</select>
  <input type="hidden" name="brand" id="brand">
  <input type="submit"></input>
</form>
```

JS:

```js
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const brandSelector = document.getElementById('brand-select');
const brandInput = document.getElementById('brand');

form.onsubmit = (e) => {
  // prevent form from submitting
  e.preventDefault();
  const formData = new FormData(form);
  // get all selected brands from the brand selector
  // and join them with '+'
  const brands = formData.getAll('brand-select').join('+');
  brandInput.value = brands;
  // disable brand selector so it;s not included in the params
  brandSelector.disabled = true;
  // finally, submit the form
  form.submit();
};
```

When you submit the form on Codepen you'll see that postman-echo displays the submitted args: `"args":{"brand":"nike+adidas+woodland"}`. You can also use the `Network` tab in devtools to check the url it was submitted to. In this case it is:
`https://postman-echo.com/get?brand=nike%2Badidas%2Bwoodland` so the urldecoded value of brand is `nike+adidas+woodland`

Comment: Thank you! I am facing a error in cosole says : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onsubmit' of null

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla Your form id has to match the one in *document.getElementById('form');* so make sure your form has an *id="form"* attribute. Also, please try the codepen example I made, it should work out of the box :)

Comment: Actually it adds a brand string query in addition to mine :( - paste.ofcode.org/tr6ZNMN6hyf3PsWhaSZAHv

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla You are using the above example wrong. You have to rename your original select to *brand-select*, and it won't be submitted. I modified your above code, it will work now: paste.ofcode.org/aRY8iLj4WKderqAYWXMiJp

Comment: but it generates a query string like : brand-select=8&brand-select=2&brand=

Comment: i have changed it to jquery like : paste.ofcode.org/nHHFELKYPwg42NZAbF4W3P , can that be problem

Comment: @LatheeshVMVilla This jQuery code is not correct, so probably that is the problem. Try something like this: paste.ofcode.org/Pq9t3qyqxv4QTg5PjFMefj

Comment: Actually my problem was related to a WordPress issue. https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/351921/form-element-name-array-type-not-working. So your answer to this question is correct. Really appreciate your efforts! Please allow me a day so that bounty to this question can be released.  :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use JQuery like this, myselect is the id of the select tag

```
var qstring="http://myexamplesite.com/store/?brand=";
$("#myselect :selected").each(function(i,item)
{ 
    qstring=qstring+"+"+$(item).val(); 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add jquery to this like just get the values your select box and concat them using `+` concatenation operator. This best you can do.
Another solution is you do on your server-side.